# Do the use cases for Apache Cassandra mostly relate to its speed and scalability rather than how its data is stored?

Tags: cassandra

Seems like the use cases I’ve heard about for Cassandra have a lot to do with handling a massive volume of data or writes.

Is there a use case for Cassandra that doesn’t relate to how massively it scales? Like certain data structures or queries that are better suited for it (similar to how RDMSs are good for handling relational data with consistency)

Answer (score 3):

From a pure data structure perspective, Apache Cassandra is a good match for requirements with:

- Key-based read patterns.
- Data that will be written once and never deleted or updated.
- Log-based data sets that may grow over time.
- Read patterns of many, small queries.
- Time series.

The underlying log-based storage engine will definitely "play nice" with those types of use cases.

Comment: This might be a silly question, but what’s the point of writing data if it’s never read?

Comment: @GregThomas Nah, not silly.  Happens all the time in clusters that back logging or observability platforms.  The idea is to write generously; read judiciously. 
 Something like 70%-80% of all data written is never read.

Comment: I mean, you'd rather have it in the event you needed it, right?

Comment: is Cassandra in the minority regarding how fast its writes are vs reads? I always thought traditional databases typically read much more than they wrote, and that reads were generally faster.

Comment: @GregThomas While Cassandra read times have drastically improved over the versions, Cassandra had some architectural choices made designed to make writes faster (or rather, unhindered).  I'd say you are correct in that most DBs don't write "fast."

Comment: @GregThomas Aaron's answer here is good (and succinct). The only addendum I'll add to what he said is "*fast*" is subjective. Most modern database systems write "*fast-enough*" for most use cases and people. Rarely do people actually hit the maximum throughput (which can be in the millions of rows+ per second written) of the database system they're using. Rather, oftentimes the bottleneck one hits is either from the hardware they provisioned or the way they architected their database. Most modern databases are within the same ballpark of read and write speeds, generally speaking.

Comment: @J.D. Nice follow-up!  You should totally convert this to be an additional answer.

Comment: Thanks, nah I think it's too generic info (given the original post was Cassandra specific) to *stand on it's own legs*. But feel free to incorporate any of it in your answer if you'd like. I just like to throw my 2 cents in whenever I see an opportunity to make it clear that most database systems are on par with each other from a performance perspective (even when it comes to big data) despite what the marketing says or other misconceptions going around the internet are. What I liked about your answer is instead of talking speed, you gave clear objective use cases that Cassandra was built for.